# how to store Name and nameId in an Map in Jolt spec?

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I want to store ***Name*** and ***nameId*** together in a map or in any *key:value* form in array or whatever so that I can use that later in my executeScript.

My condition is if Name match the incoming data then reasonId need to store or acccess. So I need to store this Name and nameId in such a way that I can easily use it later.

```json
[
  {
    "Name": "Ivor",
    "Specialty": [
      {
        "nameId": "554",
        "specialtyId": "20"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Name": "Philip",
    "Specialty": [
      {
        "nameId": "524",
        "specialtyId": "70"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Name": "Alex",
    "Specialty": [
      {
        "nameId": "594",
        "specialtyId": "90"
      }
    ]
  },
{
    "Name": "Adam",
    "Specialty": [
      {
        "nameId": "504",
        "specialtyId": "10"
      }
    ]
  }]
```

Expected output json as :

```json
{
  "Name": {
    "Ivor": [
      "554"
    ],
    "Philip": [
      "524"
    ],
    "Alex": [
      "594"
    ],
    "Adam": [
      "504"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use such a **shift** transformation spec within a **`JoltTransformJSON`** processor :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "@Specialty[0].nameId": "Name.@1,Name[]" 
                       // the outermost wrapper is Name 
                       // the value of the Name is the next level wrapper through use of .@1,Name
                       // the innermost "nameId" : <itsvalue> match by .nameId : .nameId
      }
    }
  }
]
```

or the following one as another alternative :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "Specialty": {
          "*": {
            "nameId": "Name.@3,Name[]" // need to traverse one `:` + two `{`  = three levels in order to reach the level of the "Name"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: How can I change this script if I want output like {"Name": {"554": ["Ivor"],"524": ["Philip"]}} means first Id then Name in array? Can you tell me changes over here only please

Comment: Hi @Destiel , you can replace the innermost part of the second spec with `"@2,Name": "Name.@1,nameId[]"`

Comment: Hi Barbaros, how can I make  Name field( in output) an array, it is not an array as of now it has{} curly brackets I want data of Name to be in square [] brackets, any way possible? And sorry for asking in comments, I have been banned from asking question. :(

Comment: Expected output = {"Name": ["Ivor": ["554"],"Philip": ["524"],"Alex": ["594"],"Adam": ["504"]]}

Comment: actually I am getting error while running that "arr.Name.forEach" is not a function in executeScript , so I thought might be because this output which I have mentioned above in actual question , is not in array format, so need to change that. I'm not sure

Comment: If possible to change through jolt then please let me know else I should try something different

Comment: @Destiel As I said the input should be a valid JSON, since definition of Jolt which is *A JSON to JSON transformation library*

Comment: No worries Barbaros, I really  appreciate and thankful for your time and efforts :)

Comment: Okay what changes will be done to add nameId in front of 504 or etc like this expected output {"Name": {"Ivor": ["nameId":"554"],"Philip": ["nameId":"524"],"Alex": ["nameId":"594"],"Adam": ["nameId":"504"]}}

Comment: @Destiel This is still not a valid JSON value, but if you mean to have `{
  "Ivor" : [ {
    "nameId" : "554"
  } ],
  "Philip" : [ {
    "nameId" : "524"
  } ],
  "Alex" : [ {
    "nameId" : "594"
  } ],
  "Adam" : [ {
    "nameId" : "504"
  } ]
}`, then you can use `[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "Specialty": {
          "*": {
            "nameId": "@(3,Name)[&1].&"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]`

Comment: Then,  {"Ivor": {"nameId":"554"},"Philip": {"nameId":"524"},"Alex": {"nameId":"594"},"Adam": {"nameId":"504"}} , this is valid right how can we change it to this way.

Comment: @Destiel Then use this for the last case : `[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "Specialty": {
          "*": {
            "nameId": "@(3,Name).&"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]`